# Table selection issue

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm having this weird issue with the new `Table` introduced in Xcode 13, where I cannot programmatically select the first row. (But other rows work fine)

### Reproduction:

1. Make sure that macOS Montery and Xcode 13 Beta 2 are installed
2. Paste the following code in a new blank SwiftUI project, with its deployment target set to 12.0 (macOS Montery):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [TestStruct] = []
    @State var selection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(data, selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("column", value: \.text)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                data.append(TestStruct(text: "Test"))
                selection = Set([data.last!.id])
            }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TestStruct: Identifiable {
    var text: String
    var id = UUID()
}
```

3. Run the app, and press the "Add" button
4. Observe that no selection takes place, but when you press it again, a selection should appear

How would you fix this issue? Or is this a bug on Apple's part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [TestStruct] = []
    //   @State var selection = Set<UUID>()  // <--- for multiple selections
    @State var selection: UUID? = nil  // <--- if you want just 1 selection
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(data, selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("column", value: \.text)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                data.append(TestStruct(text: "Test"))
                if let last = data.last {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // selection.insert(last.id)
                        selection = last.id
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}
```